# What are possible effects of adding a variable to a multiple-regression model?

Tags: multiple-regression, variance, linear-model, bias, iid

I read that when adding a irrelevant variable to a multiple regression, the variance of the other regression coefficients will increase.

However, does adding a relevant variable (to combat omitted variable bias) increase the other regression coefficients in the regression model? How would the variance on the other coefficients changes when I add a relevant variable?

What are the costs and benefits of adding more variable (both relevant and irrelevant)?